# Is AI already being used in the drug industry to combat the COVID-19?

Tags: reference-request, healthcare

We all have heard about how beneficial AI can be in health. There are plenty of papers and research about confronting diseases, like cancer. However, in 2020 with COVID-19 be one of the most serious health problems that have caused thousands of deaths worldwide.

Is AI already being used in the drug industry to combat the COVID-19? If yes, can you, please, provide a reference?

Comment: I have changed your question so that this post is more useful. Note that I have already asked a similar question: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/18701/2444, but your question now is slightly different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A global race is underway to discover a vaccine, drug, or combination of treatments that can disrupt the SARS-CoV-2 virus.

The problem is, there are more than a **billion** such molecules. A researcher would conceivably want to test each one against the two dozen or so proteins in **SARS-CoV-2** to see their effects. Such a project could use every wet lab in the world and still not be completed for centuries.

Computer modelling is a common approach used by academic researchers and pharmaceutical companies as a preliminary, filtering step in drug discovery. However, in this case, even every supercomputer on Earth could not test those **billion molecules** in a reasonable amount of time.

[**Folding@home**](https://foldingathome.org/) is a distributed computing project run by Stanford University. The aim of the project is to examine how proteins fold and it does this using **spare computing power**. however, there is a lot of research in progress that are harnessing the potential of **Artificial intelligence** to develop the potential treatment to combat the **COVID-19**.

Check this recent article By **Tyler Orton** in **biv** focus on how artificial intelligence is used to accelerate the process of Drug Discovery:
[**Drug research turns to artificial intelligence in COVID-19 fight**](https://biv.com/article/2020/05/drug-research-turns-artificial-intelligence-covid-19-fight)

Here are the list of some companies that are using **AI-driven** approach for Drug discovery

- [BlackThorn Therapeutics](https://www.blackthornrx.com/)
- [xscientia](https://www.exscientia.ai/)
- [Insilico Medicine](https://insilico.com/)
- [Insitro](http://insitro.com/)
- [Notable Labs](https://notablelabs.com/)
- [Standigm](http://www.standigm.com/)
- [Recursion Pharmaceuticals](https://www.recursionpharma.com/)

The Hong Kong-based company **Insilico Medicine**, a developer of comprehensive drug discovery and biomarker development platform **GENTRL**, and a pioneer in the application of **generative adversarial networks (GANs)** to drug discovery.

Insilico Medicine, Publishes a paper in September last year titled,
[**Deep learning enables rapid identification of potent DDR1 kinase inhibitors**](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41587-019-0224-x)," in a most reputed journal **Nature Biotechnology**. The paper describes a timed challenge, where the new artificial intelligence system called **Generative Tensorial Reinforcement Learning (GENTRL)** designed **six novel inhibitors of DDR1**, a **kinase target implicated in fibrosis** **and other diseases**, **in 21 days**.

Four compounds were active in biochemical assays, and two were validated in cell-based assays. One lead candidate was tested and demonstrated favorable pharmacokinetics in mice.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it is being used directly in the *industry*, but [here](https://www.lancaster.ac.uk/news/uk-scientists-develop-new-rapid-smart-testing-device-for-coronavirus) is an interesting article on research being done by 3 UK universities using AI.